# Yii2 Progress Bar in a DetailView

Tags: yii2, yii2-widget

I have a requirement of displaying the Progress Bar in `DetailView` widget. I searched for it but I got solutions for `GridView` widget. So that I tried modifying it but didn't work as expected.

```
<?=DetailView::widget(
    [
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' =>
        [
            [
                'attribute' => 'progress',
                'label' => 'Activity Progress',
                'type' => DetailView::INPUT_WIDGET,
                'class' => 'yii\bootstrap\Progress',
                'widgetOptions' =>
                [
                    'percent' => 50,
                    'barOptions' => ['class' => 'progress-bar-info'],
                    'options' => ['id' => 'progBar', 'class' => 'active progress-striped']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
)
?>
```

Comment: can you mark the ans as correct if it helped you out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply set the column `format` to `raw` and return the widget output from the `value` option simple as that see below I used the `yii\bootstrap\Progress` widget within the `DetailView`

```
<?php echo DetailView::widget(
    [
        'model' => $model,
        'attributes' =>
        [
            [
                'attribute' => 'progress',
                'label' => 'Activity Progress',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    // striped animated
                    return \yii\bootstrap\Progress::widget(
                        [
                            'percent' => 70,
                            'options' => ['class' => 'progress-success active progress-striped'],
                        ]
                    );
                },
            ],
        ],
    ]
)
?>
```

If you have a field in the database with the name `progress` that holds the current progress of the row in integer format you can pass `$model->progress` to the `percent` option in the `yii\bootstrap\Progress` widget like `"percent"=>$model->progress`.